# How can I check if a 2 numbers have the same digits PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, integer, comparison

I want to compare two int so if they contain the same digits it outputs a true,for example:

```
$a=1260
$b=2106
```

and then because both of them contain: `0126`  it outputs true how can this be made?
And if it's possible with the fewest possible lines

Comment: Convert numbers to string, split strings into two char arrays, compare arrays using `Compare-Object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one technique:

`$null -eq (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ([char[]][String]1260) -DifferenceObject ([char[]][String]2601))`

Which returns `true` or `false`, depending on if the digits are the same or not.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another, a bit lengthier solution:

```
( $a.ToString().ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object { $c = $true } { if ( $b.ToString() -notmatch $_.ToString() ) { $c = $false } } { $c } ) -and ( $b.ToString().ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object { $c = $true } { if ( $a.ToString() -notmatch $_.ToString() ) { $c = $false } } { $c } )
```

This compares the `int`'s as arrays and thus need to be run bothways.